# DATEDIF formula; Yes/No answer

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I use the current formula:

```
=IF(DATEDIF(C1,D1,"d")>=3,"Yes","No")
```

If the date in `D1` is 3 days or more after `C1` it gives an answer of `Yes`.

If the date in `D1` is less than 3 days after `C1` it gives and answer of `No`.

If `C`1 is blank it gives an answer of `Yes`. It needs to say `No`.

How do I get it to say `No` without changing the other answers?

Answer (score 2):

you just need to insert another `if statement`in between like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C1),"No",IF(DATEDIF(C1,D1,"d")>=3,"Yes","No"))
```

it should work now.

Comment: @SteveB great! then please accept it as the answer by [clicking the check mark below the vote count to the left of my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
=IF(OR(C1="",D1<C1+3),"No","Yes")
```

Returns "No" if C1 after D1.